# Best way to create my own Button

Tags: java, awt

I am currently writing a Game Engine in Java and I reached a point where I think about creating my own types of `Buttons`, `Lists` and so on.

I can't just create awt `Components` and change their behavior because I want them to have different shapes, textures etc.

Should I **extend `Button` in a new Class** , say `MyOwnButton.class` and modify it's inhitered methods or **create a new `Button`** from scratches?

What would give me a better Performance?

Comment: Yes. Never recreate the wheel.

Comment: If you really want to do that, then using Swing's `AbstractButton` or `JComponent` as the superclass is probably a good option. They are meant for light-weight components (that are drawn by Java code rather than the operating-system peer widgets) and insulate you somewhat from the problems you'd get if you inherited from `Component` directly.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Good advice, so long as the OP isn't intending to use a `BufferStrategy` to render the game, then they should be using Swing at all (and even AWT might cause issues)

Comment: I DO want to draw using BufferStrategy, but why does this cause problems?

Comment: Dp you really mean the app. is using AWT components?  Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: Hey there. I separated your paragraph in sentences which now express in a clearer way what you need. It is a good idea to write your question in a way that makes the actual sentence of the question stand out.